# How to make a custom UIView to combine with UINavigationBar make it looks as one

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

As you can see below, the three buttons: STORE,AREA and All. These buttons looks like the UINavigationBar and them are combined together. I tried in storyboard, I added a custom UIView and try to set it's colour match the UINavigationBar background color. But it always has differences, and I can see the border line between UINavigationBar and the custom UIView. How to make a UIView to combine with the UINavigationBar to make it all looks like they are combined.

[image: menu]

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 has shadow next to the navigation bar. Try below to remove that shadow:

```
if (IS_IOS7) {
  [[UINavigationBar appearance]setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the **navigation** and **status** bar background only in iOS7. For this, you can use

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The size of the `nav_bg.png` should be **320*64 px**

If you want to simply change the color of **navigation** bar you can use

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```